# RegEx in c# for a piped (|) pattern string

Tags: c#, regex

I have an multiline input string of following format

ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8

The data might run into thousands of rows
Data Type for Col1-8 could be alphanumeric or alpha only which may differ from row to row.

I need to do following:

1. Extract Col2 & Col3 out (Thinking of using Regex here instead of usual string splitting since later would be slower in my case?)
2. I want the rest of the data also in following format also. ID | Col1 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 (This I can achieve using string.Replace once I have the data in point 1)

Please note that I do not want to loose data of Col2 & Col3 while achieving solution for point 2 and hence the first point is also important to me.

I tried creating RegEx for point 1 as (|){2,4} which I understand now is completely wrong and curently I have no idea how to proceed on this using Regex.

I would be thankful for any help/pointers on how to go about creating a regex for same.

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: "since later would be slower in my case" - is that just a guess? It *sounds* like it... do you have any evidence for it? Have you tried it the simplest way and found it to be too slow?

Comment: please, forget about regexps, it is just a mainstream.. just use `splitByString(string, delim)`

Comment: I don't understand why you rejected `string.Split`. The main issue with `string.Split` is that it doesn't cope with escape sequences, but you don't mention those.

Comment: The pipe character is a special character so you'd need to escape those (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). But I agree with the others, use `string.Split` in this case.

Comment: How does that one quote go? "Faced with a problem, a developer said, 'I know, I'll use regular expressions!' Now they have two problems." Something like that anywas

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I was trying to guess that since Split would internally be using looping right? Not sure though, seems like that's the way to go about it right now.

Comment: @DrakeClarris - I understand what you are trying to say, however as a developer I also feel I should know various ways of achieving a solution. This makes us robust.

Comment: @Aditya: How would you expect a regex to work *without* any looping? And why bother guessing at all, when you can just try a simple solution and see if it's fast enough?

Comment: @Aditya: did any of the answers give you a solution? If so, please accept the one that you chose as the answer for the benefit of the contributor and the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't do it this way?

```
var str = "ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8";
var strA = str.Split(" | ".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
var strExtract = new List<string> { strA[2], strA[4] };
strA.RemoveAt(2);
strA.RemoveAt(3);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", strA.ToArray()));
```

Comment: This solution does not get the item 2 and item 3 (point 1), just remove them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cols = input.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => s.Trim())
            .ToList();

var extractedcols = cols.Skip(2).Take(2);
var output = string.Join(" | ", cols.Except(extractedcols));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .Split'|', 5) to get the first 4 elements and the rest of the sting as an array.